# react-query and using key factory generates type error when using them with useQuery

Tags: typescript, react-query

So, I am following the pattern here:

https://tkdodo.eu/blog/effective-react-query-keys

but, when I true to use my key factor with a useQuery, I get a type error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'readonly ["product"]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryKey'.   The type 'readonly ["product"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'unknown[]'.
```

// setup

```
export const productKeys = {
  all: ['product'] as const
```

// Usage

```
  return useQuery (
    productKeys.all, // TYPE ERROR HERE
    async () => {
```

Note: Its not particular to this example. It happens with all my useQueries for various keygen items from the key factory.

Comment: Which version of react query are you using? Support for readonly query keys was added some time ago…

Comment: I am using: "react-query": "^3.8.2", <--- updating to 3.17.* fixed the issue. Thanks.